# building c++ opencv 4 with cuda ubuntu 16/04

Tags: c++, opencv, cudnn

I'm trying to build opencv' with cuda 10.2. When the following command :

```
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE \
-DOPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=../../opencv_contrib/modules \
-DWITH_TBB=ON -DWITH_CUDA=ON \
-DBUILD_opencv_cudacodec=OFF \
-DENABLE_FAST_MATH=1 \
-DWITH_CUBLAS=1 \
 -DWITH_V4L=ON  \
 -DWITH_OPENGL=ON  \
 -DWITH_GSTREAMER=ON  \
 -DOPENCV_GENERATE_PKGCONFIG=ON  \
 -DOPENCV_ENABLE_NONFREE=ON \
 -DBUILD_EXAMPLES=TRUE \
 -DBUILD_PERF_TESTS=FALSE \
 -DEBUILD_TESTS=FALSE ../../opencv
```

I have the following issue :

```
Could NOT find CUDNN (missing:  CUDNN_LIBRARY CUDNN_INCLUDE_DIR) (Required is at least version "6")
```

of course I have installed cudnn7 corresponding to cuda 10.2, I the installation test passed.

Can someone help ?

Comment: "missing:  CUDNN_LIBRARY CUDNN_INCLUDE_DIR" seems pretty straightforward to fix...

Comment: of course I tried to add  CUDNN_LIBRARY and CUDNN_INCLUDE_DIR in my environment variable  in several way but it doesn't work

Comment: That is a variable inside cmake, not your environment

Comment: Please write a short answer explaining what you did to solve the problem for the next people with the same question

Comment: I added the following instruction for cmake                                                               -DCUDNN_INCLUDE_DIR=/usr/local/cuda/include \
-DCUDNN_LIBRARY=/usr/local/cuda/lib64 \

Comment: If you add that as an answer, not a comment, I will upvote it so that it is marked as an answered question. Adding a comment is not as useful or helpful

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To fix the problem I added the following options for cmake :

```
-DCUDNN_INCLUDE_DIR=/usr/local/cuda/include \
-DCUDNN_LIBRARY=/usr/local/cuda/lib64/libcudnn.so.7.6.5 \
```

Comment: If you come back in a few days you will be able to accept your own answer. Thanks for participating in the correct way

Answer (score 2):

You may also need to add:
`-DCUDNN_VERSION='7.6'`

Or in my case it was:
`-DCUDNN_VERSION='8.0'`

Comment: I had the same issue and was forced to also add the version number to make it work. As of January 2022 (OpenCV 4.5.5, CuDNN 8.3, on Windows) the corresponding CMake options look like: -DCUDNN_INCLUDE_DIR=C:\NVIDIA\CUDNN\v8.3\include -DCUDNN_LIBRARY=C:\NVIDIA\CUDNN\v8.3\lib\x64\cudnn.lib
-DCUDNN_VERSION='8.3'